# Error 500 on Apache/Linux server when accessing a git-cloned app

Tags: git, apache, internal-server-error

I have a regular Linux/Apache server (hired hosting) where I host a PHP website that I update regularly through FTP. I wanted to automatically deploy changes to the server when I push a change to its Bitbucket repository.

To start, I SSH to the server and clone the repository to a dir (say, myapp):

```
git clone [myapp GIT URL]
```

When I go to http://mydomain.com/myapp I get **Internal Server Error (500)**. I figured it had something to do with permissions or file ownership. Through FTP, i `chmod` all files to 777 and it *still* throws the same error. In fact, I can delete the directory's content and upload the app manually through FTP and the error will persist (The dir's permissions are also set to  777). The only way to fix it is to delete the directory and create it again and upload the app manually.

Like I said, it's a paid hosting service so I do not own the server or have any sort of advanced control over it.

Why does this happen? Is it fixable from my end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found this question because I had the same problem and i couldn't find an answer anywhere so this is for everyone in the future that'll find this question.

You have to edit your bashrc file

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

And add this to the bottom of the file

```
umask 022
```

After this you have to logout and login before this will take effect (if you're logged in using ssh just connect again) or execute the file

```
.  ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can git clone again and it'll work.

You can find the documentation for [umask here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uumask.htm)

Comment: I had completely forgotten about this question. I managed to fix it using this some time ago and yes, it works perfectly. Thank you for answering!